# How do I reference ImageView/ImageButton to enum values in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, enums

I have these 6 colour images that will either be used as ImageView or ImageButton they are coded like this:

```
R.drawable.bluePeg
R.drawable.redPeg
R.drawable.greenPeg
R.drawable.purplePeg
R.drawable.brownPeg
R.drawable.yellowPeg
```

I want them to be linked to enum values so I can better compare them in an array something like this:

```
public enum Colours {
    RED, BLUE, YELLOW, BROWN,
    GREEN, PURPLE;
}
```

My question is how can I use enum to link these images to the correct values so I can then start using arrays for them to better reference.

Hope this makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create constructor for enum Colours:

```
public enum Colours {

    RED(R.drawable.redPeg), ... BLUE(R.drawable.bluePeg);

    private final int drawable;

    private Colours(int drawable) {
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }

    public int getDrawable() {
        return this.drawable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with a HashMap, for example:

```
Map<String, Integer> colors = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
colors.put("RED", R.drawable.redPeg);
// etc, put all the values
```

Retrieve the values like:

```
colors.get("RED"); // will return R.drawable.redPeg
```